# How to solve the update bundler warning in rails when deploying to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler, railstutorial.org

How do I solve the following warning? I updated my ruby version to 2.3.1 and rails version to 4.2.6. I get this warning when I push my app to heroku.

```
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Removing mime-types-data (3.2016.0221)
```

I removed the Gemfile.lock and ran bundle install and also tried to update the bundler but the warning never goes away .

```
suramai@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/converse (master) $ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.12.4
1 gem installed
suramai@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/converse (master) $
```

Comment: read [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version)

Answer (score 66):

So it's complaining that the version of bundler installed on heroku is older than the version you used to create your `Gemfile.lock` on your dev machine.

You can probably just ignore the warning -- in most cases installing with a slightly older version of bundler than you used to create the `Gemfile.lock` is just fine.

bundler recently added the recording of the version of bundler used  in the `Gemfile.lock`, and then the subsequent warning, because in some cases a new feature added to a new version of bundler might have been used to create the `Gemfile.lock`, such that installing with an older version might not work right. So sometimes it can be a problem. Although usually it won't be.

[It doesn't look like you can get heroku to install with a different version of bundler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version).

If you want to make the warning go away, you could instead choose to use the same version of bundler locally that heroku uses. It's a bit hard to figure out exactly what version of bundler heroku is using -- it would be nice if that warning line actually told you the two different versions of bundler involved! But it doesn't.

[This heroku support doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#libraries) suggests that heroku is using bundler `1.11.2`. (Right now; it could change in the future!). We can see from your log that you are using `1.12.4`.  If you want to use `1.11.2` instead, to avoid the warning, then, remove all versions of bundler installed on your system:

```
 gem uninstall bundler
```

Then install `1.11.2` specifically:

```
 gem install bundler -v 1.11.2
```

In general, when you use the `bundle` command, it will use the latest version installed on your system, so to make sure you are always using `1.11.2`, make sure that's the latest version installed on your system, and never install a later one.

Then you need to regenerate your `Gemfile.lock` such that it says it was bundled with `1.11.2`, to not get the warning anymore. This is kind of pain, the easiest thing to do might be to edit the `Gemfile.lock` by hand, and then going forward only ever use bundler `1.11.2`.

To use bundler `1.11.2` even if you do want to have later versions of bundler installed on your system, then every time you do a `bundle install` or `bundle update` (for an app that will be deployed to heroku anyway), you could do it as:

```
 bundle _1.11.2_ install
```

etc. That will tell rubygems to run the bundle install command with bundler version `1.11.2`, and then that version will be recorded in the `Gemfile.lock`, and you won't get the warning.

This is all a bit of a mess. Many developers probably just ignore the warning. It should normally be fine.

Comment: `Gem bundler-2.1.2 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem` ☹️